# using data binding in onclick url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, url, data-binding

I am using this [cordova plugin](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git) to launch external urls in my [Ionic App](http://ionicframework.com/) this is my code that works well.

```
<a class="orange" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.myurl/privacy-policy', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">Privacy Policy</a>
```

However I would like to use data binding within the URL.

How can I achieve the following:

```
 <a class="orange" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.myurl/{{privacy.policy}}', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">Privacy Policy</a>
```

it just prints it out as if it was a string. I have tried playing with the quotes however everything either breaks it or prints out a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dZ6CGCLPCA3tMnCO8vjo?p=preview) is a Plunker I made with the same concept. I changed the onclick to ng-click and handled the window opening in the controller.

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getWindow = function() {
        window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q='+ $scope.input.search, '_system', 'location=yes');
    }
});
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="input.search" />

    <p><a class="orange" href ng-click="getWindow()">Open Google</a></p>
</body>
```

A user types in a query, and when the link is clicked, google is launched in a new window with the query in the url.

Comment: Ignore the $http module, that is unnecessary and I forgot to remove it. Also you have in your code href="#". Defining the href with an anchor (as most webdevs are used to) can and will mess with the Angular routing. Use href by itself instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to access angular scope form non angular html part then you need to do use `angular.element($0).scope()` which would give you access of scope.

```
 <a class="orange" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.myurl/'+ angular.element($0).scope().privacy.policy, '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
Privacy Policy</a>
```

If your current code is in angular js the do use `ng-click` instead of `onclick`

```
 <a class="orange" href="#" ng-click="window.open('http://www.myurl/'+ privacy.policy, '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
Privacy Policy</a>
```

Comment: getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $0 is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

**See the JSFiddle or the gist:**

- https://gist.github.com/rewonc/e53ad3a9d6ca704d402e38
- http://jsfiddle.net/sxcjmoj5/3/50

---

```
myApp.filter('hrefToJS', function ($sce, $sanitize) {
    return function (text) {
        var regex = /href="([\S]+)"/g;
        var newString = $sanitize(text).replace(regex, "onClick=\"window.open('$1', '_blank', 'location=yes')\"");
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(newString);
    }
});
```

**In your html template:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
         <h1>Before</h1>

        <p ng-bind-html="html"></p>
        <p ng-bind-html="plaintext"></p>
         <h1>After</h1>

        <p ng-bind-html="html | hrefToJS"></p>
        <p ng-bind-html="plaintext | linky | hrefToJS"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Your data bound to the scope:**

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.html = "This a link: <a href='https://www.google.com'>Google</a> :)";
    $scope.plaintext = "This is a link: https://www.google.com :) "
});
```

*You need to include ngSanitize for this, but you can also cut out those sections if you really want to.*